# Cannot load Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, linux, nokogiri

I'm writing Ruby scripts on Linux Mint 14 under RVM. In both Ruby 2.0 and 1.9.3, when I try to run what I'm working on, I get the error:

```
/home/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- Nokogiri (LoadError)
from /home/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from make_index.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Nokogiri is installed; `gem list` gives:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
mini_portile (0.5.1)
minitest (2.5.1)
nokogiri (1.6.0)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.1)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
```

The file in question starts with `require 'Nokogiri'`. Running the file with `sudo` doesn't make a difference, nor does using the terminal vs. running it in Geany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not `Nokogiri` rather, you should write as below

```
require 'nokogiri'
```

See [**SYNOPSIS:**](http://nokogiri.org/README_rdoc.html)